# Conditional Frequency Distribution using Browns Corpus NLTK Python

Tags: python-3.x, nltk, corpus

I am trying to determine the words ending with 'ing' or 'ed'. Compute conditional frequency distibution, where condition is ['government', 'hobbies'] and the event is either 'ing' or 'ed'. Store the conditional frequency distribution in the variable inged_cfd.

Below is my Code :-

```
from nltk.corpus import brown
import nltk

genre_word = [ (genre, word.lower())
              for genre in ['government', 'hobbies']
              for word in brown.words(categories = genre) if (word.endswith('ing') or word.endswith('ed')) ]
            
genre_word_list = [list(x) for x in genre_word]

for wd in genre_word_list:
    if wd[1].endswith('ing'):
      wd[1] = 'ing'
    elif wd[1].endswith('ed'):
      wd[1] = 'ed'
      
inged_cfd = nltk.ConditionalFreqDist(genre_word_list)
        
inged_cfd.tabulate(conditions = ['government', 'hobbies'], samples = ['ed','ing'])
```

I want to output to the in a tabular format, using this above code I am getting the output as :-

```
            ed  ing 
government 2507 1605 
   hobbies 2561 2262
```

Whereas the actual output is :-

```
            ed  ing 
government 2507 1474 
   hobbies 2561 2169
```

Kindly resolve my issue, and help me get the exact output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Need to exclude the stopwords. Also while checking for ends with condition change the case to lower. Working code as follows:

```
from nltk.corpus import brown
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english')) 
genre_word = [ (genre, word.lower()) 
for genre in brown.categories() for word in brown.words(categories=genre) if (word.lower().endswith('ing') or word.lower().endswith('ed')) ]
genre_word_list = [list(x) for x in genre_word]

for wd in genre_word_list:
    if wd[1].endswith('ing') and wd[1] not in stop_words:
        wd[1] = 'ing'
    elif wd[1].endswith('ed') and wd[1] not in stop_words:
        wd[1] = 'ed'
  
inged_cfd = nltk.ConditionalFreqDist(genre_word_list)    
inged_cfd.tabulate(conditions = cfdconditions, samples = ['ed','ing'])
```

Answer (score 3):

Using same `cfdconditions` variable in both the place is creating the problem. Actually in python everything works as a object reference so when you used `cfdconditions` first time it might got changed when you passed into `cdev_cfd.tabulate` and when you are passing next time it is passed as a changed one. Better if you initialise one more list then pass that one to second call.

Here is my modification

```
from nltk.corpus import brown

from nltk.corpus import stopwords

def calculateCFD(cfdconditions, cfdevents):
    stop_words= stopwords.words('english')
    at=[i for i in cfdconditions]
    nt = [(genre, word.lower())
          for genre in cfdconditions
          for word in brown.words(categories=genre) if word not in stop_words and word.isalpha()]

    cdv_cfd = nltk.ConditionalFreqDist(nt)
    cdv_cfd.tabulate(conditions=cfdconditions, samples=cfdevents)
    nt1 = [(genre, word.lower())
          for genre in cfdconditions
          for word in brown.words(categories=genre) ]
    
    temp =[]
    for we in nt1:
        wd = we[1]
        if wd[-3:] == 'ing' and wd not in stop_words:
            temp.append((we[0] ,'ing'))

        if wd[-2:] == 'ed':
            temp.append((we[0] ,'ed'))
        

    inged_cfd = nltk.ConditionalFreqDist(temp)
    a=['ed','ing']
    inged_cfd.tabulate(conditions=at, samples=a)
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Expected output is -

```
                 many years 

        fiction    29    44 

      adventure    24    32 

science_fiction    11    16 

                  ed  ing 

        fiction 2943 1767 

      adventure 3281 1844 

science_fiction  574  293
```

and

```
                  good    bad better 

      adventure     39      9     30 

        fiction     60     17     27 

science_fiction     14      1      4 

        mystery     45     13     29 

                  ed  ing 

      adventure 3281 1844 

        fiction 2943 1767 

science_fiction  574  293 

        mystery 2382 1374
```

Comment: ishan Kankane share the code above and that is working perfectly. The different what I noticed is

1) use of isalpha() (though it's not mentioned in question) - try to add that as well

2) while genertaing the list (of 'ing' and 'ed') - generally I saw it's a list of tuples...but in code we are using list of list (try to convert that as well )

3) while generating the (genre, word) in If condition - he is not using if word.lower() not in stopwords, he just used if word is not in stopwords  - Try this as well

Answer (score 0):

I have used this approach, it has less lines of code and faster

```
from nltk.corpus import brown
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
    stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))
    cdev_cfd = nltk.ConditionalFreqDist([(genre, word.lower()) for genre in cfdconditions
          for word in brown.words(categories=genre) if word.lower() not in stop_words])
    
    inged_cfd = nltk.ConditionalFreqDist([(genre, word[-3:].lower() if word.lower().endswith('ing') else word[-2:].lower()) 
                                          for genre in conditions for word in brown.words(categories=genre) 
                                          if word.lower() not in stop_words and  (word.lower().endswith('ing') or word.lower().endswith('ed'))])
    
    cdev_cfd.tabulate(conditions=conditions, samples=cfdevents)
    
    inged_cfd.tabulate(conditions=conditions, samples=['ed','ing'])
```

Answer (score -1):

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords,brown
def calculateCFD(cfdconditions, cfdevents):
    # Write your code here
    stop_words=set(stopwords.w`enter code here`ords("english"))
    list1=[(genre,word.lower()) for genre in cfdconditions for word in brown.words(categories=genre) if word.lower() not in stop_words]
    cfd1=nltk.ConditionalFreqDist(list1)
    cfd1_tabulate=cfd1.tabulate(conditions=cfdconditions,samples=cfdevents)
    #print(cfd1_tabulate)
    
    list2=[[genre,word.lower()] for genre in cfdconditions for word in brown.words(categories=genre) if word.lower() not in stop_words if (word.lower().endswith("ed") or word.lower().endswith("ing"))]
    for elem in list2:
        if elem[1].endswith("ed"):
            elem[1]="ed"
        else:
            elem[1]="ing"
            
    cfd2=nltk.ConditionalFreqDist(list2)
    cfd2_tabulate=cfd2.tabulate(conditions=cfdconditions,samples=["ed","ing"])
    #print(cfd2_tabulate)
    
    return cfd1_tabulate,cfd2_tabulate
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO community! You're always encouraged to add some text to explain what your code does, instead of pasting it by itself!